# Google Cloud Message with PhoneGap (share values between Activity and GCMIntentService)

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make an application that gets push notification with PhoneGap libaries.

Running sample client-side code (MainActivity & GCMIntentService) and 
server-side code(PHP version).

The problem is :

Because I'm making app with PhoneGap, I want to do something onto Webview(for PhoneGap) when I got push message. However, what receives message is the callback (onMessage) in GCM Intent Service.

How can I let MainActivity knows that GCM Intent Service took push message from server?

I considered .. what I did in iOS, like Key-Value-Observing, singleton, etc...
But It's different.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question in my project.

What I did was have a `public static Activity` in `GCMIntentService`. In every Activity I set this value to `this` in `onResume()` and set to `null` in `onPause()` Now I think GCMIntentService runs on another thread, so you need to make this threadsafe. If the value of the Activity is null I showed an notification. If not I let the Activity handle it.